# sendgrid unsubscribe formatting

Tags: sendgrid

I'm pressed for time and inherited a sendgrid implementation.  There is an unsubscribe option coming across looking like this:

```
click="" here="">.</>
```

How do I 
1) remove the unsubscribe option?
2) Format the link to something perty?

Comment: Can you provide more code? This isn't very clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics about your account configuration, I'm guessing that you probably have the "Subscription Tracking" app enabled in your account.  Your options are to (a) use the WYSIWYG editor to change it to something nice or (b) disable the app and do subscription tracking yourself with your own links.

If you sign in to SendGrid and navigate to [the "Apps" tab](http://sendgrid.com/app) at the very top of the page,  you'll see a list of the apps you have on.  It should look something like this:

[image: SendGrid Apps dashboard]

What you're looking for is [the "Subscription Tracking" app](http://sendgrid.com/app/appSettings/type/subscriptiontrack/id/5).  If you click on "settings" next to the app title, you'll be taken to a screen where you can edit the link and behavior.  You can alternatively click "disable" to turn it off entirely and implement your own.

If you're still having issues, you can always open a ticket on [our support team](http://support.sendgrid.com/).

Comment: this looks very promising.  I'll look into this tonight, thank again, I just inherited this thing and didn't even know there was a front end.

Comment: No worries.  There's also APIs to do all this if you prefer.  As I said, reach out to support if you have any issues.  They're available 24/7

Comment: that was it, I'll pass it back over to the business to correct.  Thank you so much.

Comment: nostalgic seeing this image of the sendgrid dashboard :)

Answer (score -1):

In the SendGrid control panel for your account, you can change the option to define whether unsubscribe appears or not.  This is a global setting change.

Or, when you create the message (depending on how you create it), you can define whether the unsubscribe link appears or not.  For example, if you are using the SendGrid C# library, this option is available.  It's not available if you're creating the message via standard SMTP libs, like .Net's MailMessage class.  This is a per-message setting change.

There's no default way to change how an unsubscribe link appears AFAIK, beyond CSS formatting.